# Different URLS same install with custom content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

What is the most efficient way to do the following scenario:

I have one site where there are 2 different store locations. Some content is different but most of the content is the same across the store locations, for example the store products are the same for both sites.

Scenarios
A user types http://www.storegroup.com:
- They get to a landing page with links to the 2 stores: clicking any of the 2 stores goes to the link as described below.

A user types http://www.store1.com:
- They get to a landing page with a custom menu for this store with content that is shared across store 1 and 2 (ecommerce) and some unique content (ex.: about us page)

A user types http://www.store2.com:
- They get to a landing page with a custom menu for this store with content that is shared across store 1 and 2 (ecommerce) and some unique content (ex.: about us page)

All of this I would like to manage with one copy of a site that has shared content across the 2 stores and some unique content. Based on the URL they arrived from it shows the content related to this store...

I've researched this quite a bit but never quite arrived at my scenario. Creating a WordPress multi-site came close but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: dont have a site per store. have one site, list which store has stock on a product page

Comment: @Dagon thanks for your reply and I would agree. But in this case we don't have a choice, we need to figure out how to have 2 unique sites with their own URL and unique content, and have some shared content across...writing dozens of .htaccess rules is another but not 100% convinced it's the right way to go.